# Timing quartz task execution duration

Tags: java, spring, profiling, quartz-scheduler

Is there a standard way of logging the time Quartz takes to execute a task? I'm open to Spring based solutions as well, as I'm using both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a [JobListener](http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/api/org/quartz/JobListener.html) and add it as a [global job listener](http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/api/org/quartz/core/QuartzScheduler.html#addGlobalJobListener(org.quartz.JobListener)) to the scheduler.

This will give you some hooks on when a job is about to be executed and when it has finished executing. You should be able to do something with these hooks to record the start and end times of the jobs, and then log the run time.

Comment: links are outdated (dead).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a general purpose timing library, such as [ERMA](http://erma.wikidot.com/). It integrates very nicely with spring.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `JobListener` for that. The execution time of a job is even provided by the context. The Listener need to be added to the used `Scheduler`:

```
public class GlobalJobRuntimeListener implements JobListener {
    //... other methods to overwrite 

    @Override
    public void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException) {
        System.out.println("Job with key " + context.getJobDetail().getKey().toString()
                + " finished in " + context.getJobRunTime() + " ms.");
    }
}
```

-

```
Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
scheduler.getListenerManager().addJobListener(new GlobalJobRuntimeListener());
scheduler.start();
```